# pgadmin 4 1.4/1.5 not launching on windows

Tags: pgadmin

I installed pgadmin 4 1.5 desktop on windows 10, but when I try launching it, I can see the splash screen, then it disappear and nothing more append.

In the task manager, I can see it running, and consuming CPU in the first seconds, but the UI never show up.

I have the same problem on pgadmin 4 1.4, but weirdly, 1.3 works well.

As 1.3 works, I will use it, but if anyone know what is happening, I will appreciate help.

Thank you

Comment: Same with me. And I desparately need version 1.5 as there was a bugfix for daterange[] display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some help here :
http://www.postgresql-archive.org/pgAdmin-4-v1-3-fails-to-load-td5951102.html

I downloaded this 1.5 version and it launched normally, btw I didn't check if everything is running as expected :
https://developer.pgadmin.org/~dpage/pgadmin4-1.5-x86.exe

hope it helps

Comment: I am having issues with 1.5. It just does not start and is stuck on start screen for infinity

Comment: After using pgadmin for a while, I switched to Dbeaver. It has all I need and more.

Answer (score 0):

Because of my computer name includes non-English characters, I had this problem. After changing my computer name with English characters, problem disappeared; Hope this helps;